# How do I change the date/time format displayed in the Bokeh hovertool?

Tags: python, datetime, tooltip, bokeh

Currently the Bokeh hovertool spits out my date values as a 13-digit number. How do I change the format of how it's displayed?

Below is my code...also I've specified which line of code the date/time is in.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.io import output_notebook

x = dff.P2_VWC
y = dff.P2_EC
bok = figure(title="Simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')
bok.line(x, y, legend_label="Hysteresis", line_width=2)
show(bok)
output_notebook()

#Specify the selection tools to be made available
select_tools = ['box_select', 'lasso_select', 'poly_select', 'tap', 'reset']

# Format the tooltip
tooltips = [ 
            ('VWC', '@P2_VWC'),
            ('EC', '@P2_EC'),
            ('Date', '@date_time') # !THIS DATE NEEDS FORMATTED!
           ]

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400, x_axis_type='linear', title = "VWC v. Bulk EC")
p.line(x="P2_VWC", y="P2_EC", source=dff)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'VWC'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Bulk EC'
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips))
show(p)
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: There is an entire section of the docs dedicated to just this: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields

Answer (score 0):

Only a few lines of code needed to be changed but they are below. {%F %T} can be added to the date/time code to specify what you want.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.io import output_notebook

output_notebook()

#Specify the selection tools to be made available
select_tools = ['box_select', 'lasso_select', 'poly_select', 'tap', 'reset']

# Format the tooltip
# https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter
tooltips = [ 
            ('VWC', '@P2_VWC'),
            ('EC', '@P2_EC'),
            ('Date', '@date_time{%F %T}'),
           ]

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=800, x_axis_type='linear', title = "VWC v. Bulk EC")
p.line(x="P2_VWC", y="P2_EC", source=df1)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'VWC'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Bulk EC'
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips, formatters={'@date_time': 'datetime'}))
show(p)
```